# Area bounded by $(\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|})^{12}=xy$ , how to convert this to polar equation, what to do with absolute values?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, problem-solving, polar-coordinates

[image]

The only problem finding the limits of integration. Thats why i want to convert to polar. I want to make a substitution so that the limits of r can be easily evaluated.   I was thinking of  $$ x=r^2 cos^2 \phi $$ $$ y=r^2 sin^2 \phi $$

The absolute values scare me a little.  I am not sure if they even change anything, r is positive, but i dont know what to do with absolute values of trig functions.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it doesn't appear particularly useful.  The earlier identities are one way of addressing the absolute values of the trig functions; however, less clear that polar conversion (and your suggestion is not standard, so you have to be careful about lots of details, like Jacobian determinants and limits on $\theta$) is the correct way to go.

Comment: Another thought - the bounding curve has no answer when x and y are of opposite sign, so you can restrict it to the first and third quadrants.  Then by symmetry the total area has to be double the first quadrant area, and in the first quadrant both sin and cosine are positive.

Comment: @JohnPolcari Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shape 
$$B:\quad\bigl(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}\bigr)^{12}\leq xy,\quad x\geq0,\quad y\geq0\tag{1}$$
in the first quadrant makes up half the required area (see the figure in Cesareo's answer). We first set up a parametrization of $B$ of the following form:
$$\psi:\quad\left\{\eqalign{x= u\cos^4 t\cr y=u\sin^4 t\cr}\right.\qquad\left(0\leq u\leq \bar u(t), \ 0\leq t\leq{\pi\over2}\right)\ .\tag{2}$$
Here the exponent $4$ of $\cos$ and $\sin$ was chosen such that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$ comes out particularly simple. Note that the $u$-lines $t={\rm const.}$ are rays emanating from $(0,0)$ out into the first quadrant. In order to determine the upper $u$-limit $\bar u(t)$ for given $t$ we plug $(2)$ into $(1)$ and obtain $u^6\leq u^2\cos^4 t\sin^4 t$. It follows that 
$$0\leq u\leq \bar u(t)=\cos t\sin t\ .$$
From $(2)$ one computes
$$d\psi(u,t)=\left[\matrix{\cos^4 t&-4u\cos^3 t\sin t\cr \sin^4 t&4u\sin^3 t\cos t\cr}\right]\ ,$$
leading to the Jacobian
$$J_\psi(u,t)=4u\cos^3 t\sin^3 t\ .$$
In this way we obtain
$$\eqalign{{\rm area}(B)&=\int_B 1\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\bar u(t)} J_\psi(u,t)\>du\>dt\cr &=\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^3 t\sin^3 t\> \bigl(2\bar u^2(t)\bigr)\>dt\cr  &=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^5 t\>\sin^5 t\>dt={1\over30}\ .\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have some questions. First, shouldnt we multiply the final result by 2 because of the area in the third quadrant. Second, would parametrization i suggested work(does any sub work if you evaluate the limits properly). Finally, what is the thinking process when switching to polar(or spherical) coordinates. Is the idea to substitute in the way which makes the limits r ( or u as you wrote) easiest to evaluate.

Comment: Every substitution done correctly is allowed. It is a matter of expertise to choose the substitution that leads quickly to the hoped for simple result. I didn't go through your proposed approach.

Answer (score 2):

After substitution of

$$
x = r \cos\theta\\
y = r \sin\theta
$$

the polar representation can be obtained as

$$
r = \frac{\sqrt[4]{\sin (\theta ) \cos (\theta )}}{\left(\sqrt{\left| \sin (\theta )\right| }+\sqrt{\left| \cos (\theta )\right| }\right)^3}
$$

with result

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help